# Solving complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers

> The value of $(-8\sqrt{-1})^{\left(\frac 16\right)}+(8\sqrt{-1})^{\left(\frac 16\right)}$ is a pure real number. Can you find the real number?

**My try:**
$$(-8\sqrt{-1})^{\left(\frac 16\right)}+(8\sqrt{-1})^{\left(\frac 16\right)}\\
=i^{\frac 16}(\sqrt2 i+\sqrt 2)
$$
But, how can I find that this is a real number. Please help.

Comment: You're going too fast! With complex numbers it's not always true that $(ab)^c = a^c b^c$. Carefully check what definition of exponentiation you're using, and evaluate each of the two terms you're adding separately.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen But, is there any other way I can do?

Answer (score 5):

We have $-8i=8e^{\frac{-i\pi}{2}}$ and $8i=8e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$ using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), so

$(-8i)^{\frac{1}{6}}+(8i)^{\frac{1}{6}}=8^{\frac{1}{6}}(e^{\frac{-i\pi}{12}}+e^{\frac{i\pi}{12}})=2 \times 8^{\frac{1}{6}}\times\frac{e^{\frac{-i\pi}{12}}+e^{\frac{i\pi}{12}}}{2}=2 \times 8^{\frac{1}{6}}cos(\frac{\pi}{12})$  where we have used that $cos(\theta)=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$.